# Tab not found in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, tls1.2

While reading an article about TLS decryption, I found this image

[image]

where a tab named "Decrypted SSL Data" in wireshark exists. But, in my Wireshark(version 2.2.5), I cannot find this tab. How can I find this tab or something that may show me the decrypted ssl data?

Answer (score 1):

Since Wireshark version 1.6 you can also use so called (Pre)-Master-Secret file that can be generated by Chrome or Firefox.

There are some details on Wireshark wiki what needs to be done.
[Using the (Pre)-Master-Secret](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#Using_the_.28Pre.29-Master-Secret)

Please note this will not work Diffie-Hellman cipher, and this must be disabled in your browser. There some instructions how to do it here:
[Walkthrough: Decrypt SSL/TLS traffic (HTTPS and HTTP/2) in Wireshark](http://www.joji.me/en-us/blog/walkthrough-decrypt-ssl-tls-traffic-https-and-http2-in-wireshark)

There are many more resources on the net about the subject.
Please try those links below:

- [Decrypting TLS Browser Traffic With Wireshark – The Easy Way!](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/)
- [Decrypt HTTPS traffic with Wireshark and Fiddler](https://www.hhutzler.de/blog/decrypt-https-traffic-wireshark-fiddler/)
- [Using Wireshark to Decode SSL/TLS Packets](https://packetpushers.net/using-wireshark-to-decode-ssltls-packets/)

If (Pre)-Master-Secret file approach does not work for you please try Fiddler which use a proxy approach and you should be able to decrypt SSL traffic with dedicated certificate that needs to be installed on your device. You can find quick guide here: [Configure Fiddler to Decrypt HTTPS Traffic](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first supply the RSA encryption key to Wireshark so it can decrypt the SSL traffic for you.  You can refer to the [Wireshark SSL](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) wiki page for how to do that.